# How to play large streaming videos in Silverlight?

Tags: media-player, silverlight-5.0

In my XAML file, I have:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" AutoPlay="True"  Stretch="Uniform" Width="493" Height="270"  CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
```

In the code-behind file:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri("https://12.mp4");
```

This is working fine with files smaller than 50MB.
But large files can take 20-30 minutes to play.
How can I get faster streaming?

I'm expecting a player like YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like (the project formerly known as) SMF: https://smf.codeplex.com/

It's the official solution for all kinds of media players.